# "[serve] The api entry could not be loaded" in SharePoint Framework(SPFX)

Tags: spfx-webparts

SPFX webpart created successfully but when I run `gulp serve` command I get error.

> Error : [serve] The api entry could not be loaded: node_modules/@microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench/lib/api/

-- Node.js command prompt out put

> [12:19:56] Starting subtask 'write-manifests'...
>   [12:19:56] Finished subtask 'write-manifests' after 334 ms
>   [12:19:56] Starting subtask 'serve'...
>   [12:19:57] Error - [serve] The api entry could not be loaded:  node_modules/@microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench/lib/api/
>   [12:19:57] Finished subtask 'serve' after 409 ms
>   [12:19:57] Finished 'serve' after 5.66 s
>   [12:19:57] Server started https://localhost:4321
>   [12:19:57] LiveReload started on port 35729
>   [12:19:57] Opening https://localhost:5432/workbench using the default OS app
>   [12:19:57] ==================[ Finished ]==================
>   Error - [serve] The api entry could not be loaded: node_modules/@microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench/lib/api/
>   [12:19:58] Project test version: 0.0.1
>   [12:19:58] Build tools version: 2.5.3
>   [12:19:58] Node version: v6.11.0
>   [12:19:58] Total duration: 8.68 s
>   [12:19:58] Task errors: 1

Answer (score 5):

I got a answer from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench)

Run this command

```
npm i @microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench
```